# Cannot create an external hadoop table in db2

Tags: hadoop, db2

i have a problem with creating an external hadoop table in db2.
I use this create statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL HADOOP TABLE DATA_LAKE.TABLE_TEST (
Id int,
blabla varchar(10)
)
```

but when i run this i got an error saying:

> The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name
> "TABLE_TEST" of type "Table".. SQLCODE=-601,SQLSTATE=42710.

On my file share i don't have any table name with this name and also in db2 under DATA_LAKE schema i don't have any TABLE_TEST table. I also tried to find where is this table, maybe in a catalog , but i didn't find anything.

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
WHERE TABNAME LIKE '%TABLE_TEST%'
```

Please for any help

Comment: When searching the Db2 catalog views , don't assume fixed case name, so try ` WHERE UPPER(tabname) like '%TABLE_TEST%' `  (same for schema name).

Comment: There may be additional information in the diagnostic log at the time of failure.

Comment: Probably my user doesn't have right to see all the tables. Is anyway some solution to list all the tables from BIGSQL for each user?